# How Do You Run A Node.js Prompt Lighthouse Audit From command prompt in desktop mode?

Tags: node.js, cmd

How Do You Run A Node.js Prompt Lighthouse Audit From command prompt in desktop mode?

Comment: The documentation seems pretty clear: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#using-the-node-cli

Comment: I just wanted to store the copy/paste of the commands somewhere online. I figured, other people probably want a copy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the third time I had to figure out how to do it so I figured I'd make a post on here.

DESKTOP COMMAND

```
lighthouse https://example.com/ --preset=desktop --view
```

MOBILE COMMAND (Default Audit)

```
lighthouse https://example.com/ --view
```